# Pipeline succeeds in GitHub Actions but not locally

Tags: c++, docker, github-actions

**Question:(1)**What is the reason, why my local compile does not work, but the github action pipeline does work**?:

**(Related) Question (2)**: How can i run a github docker pipeline locally?**. Bear in mind, that I want to have an interactive bash terminal running after the pipeline succeeds. So I want to actually just have e.g. the exact docker image github actions is using, so I can reproduce the pipeline locally but still be able to interactively execute commands in said environment.

Context (if anyone is interested):

My main goal is to simply get [this repository](https://github.com/evilpoke/ppsat) compiled on my machine. A GitHub Actions workflow succeeds to compile all of the source and pass all tests, however I can not reproduce the same on my machine using a Docker container of the same Ubuntu version the Github Action pipeline is using.

On github actions i use this config:

```yaml
name: artifact
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  functionalities:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 30
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install gtest manually
      run: ls & pwd & sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev && cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt && sudo make && sudo cp ./lib/*.a /usr/lib && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a
    - name: install emp
      run: |
        ls
        pwd
        wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emp-toolkit/emp-readme/master/scripts/install.py
        python3 install.py --deps --tool --ot --sh2pc
        sudo ldconfig      
    - name: Create Build Environment
      run: pwd & ls && cmake . && make
    - name: Test Functionalities
      working-directory: ./test
      run: |
       ls
       pwd
       ./runTests.sh
```

### Reproduction:

Locally:

1. I clone the repo
2. I set up a container with this Dockerfile now being placed in the repo:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:22.04

   WORKDIR /root


   RUN apt-get update && \
         apt-get -y install sudo

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
     software-properties-common \
     build-essential \
     cmake \
     git \
     libssl-dev \
     wget \
     python3 \
     vim
   ```
3. I do

   - `docker build .`
   - then `docker run -t -d -v $(pwd):/root [image id]`
   - then `sudo docker exec -it [container id] bash`
   - then this dependency `sudo apt install libgtest-dev && cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt && sudo make && sudo cp ./lib/*.a /usr/lib` (according to the README)
   - then I install another dependency required manually with `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emp-toolkit/emp-readme/master/scripts/install.py && python3 install.py -install --tool --ot --sh2pc --ag2pc` (according to the readme with `-install` added; i also tried without that option)
   - then i do `cd /root` as that's where the codebase is mounted to in the container
   - and do `cmake .` and `make`

   `make` gets me this error:

   ```
   root@b2e562f15544:~# make
   [  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/clause.cpp.o
   [  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/formula.cpp.o
   [ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/heuristics.cpp.o
   [ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/literal.cpp.o
   [ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/model.cpp.o
   [ 24%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/parser.cpp.o
   [ 28%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/ppsat.cpp.o
   [ 32%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/solver.cpp.o
   [ 36%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/state.cpp.o
   [ 40%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Ppsat.dir/utils.cpp.o
   [ 44%] Linking CXX static library libPpsat.a
   [ 44%] Built target Ppsat
   [ 48%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/ppsat.dir/ppsat.cpp.o
   [ 52%] Linking CXX executable ppsat
   [tag:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find] -lgmp: No such file or directory
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ppsat.dir/build.make:98: src/ppsat] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: src/CMakeFiles/ppsat.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
   ```

   I get a linking error.

On GitHub:

1. Trigger the pipeline (as a file `.github/workflows/main.yml` with releases enabled, pipeline triggers automatically)
2. As output I get a clean log:

   ```
   2023-11-30T10:09:36.0756406Z Requested labels: ubuntu-latest
   2023-11-30T10:09:36.0756678Z Job defined at: evilpoke/ppsat/.github/workflows/main.yml@refs/heads/main
   [...]
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0040729Z Current runner version: '2.311.0'
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0068620Z ##[group]Operating System
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0069318Z Ubuntu
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0069769Z 22.04.3
   [...]
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0075605Z ##[group]Runner Image Provisioner
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0076092Z 2.0.321.1
   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0076427Z ##[endgroup]

   [...]

   2023-11-30T10:09:44.0086134Z ##[endgroup]

   [...bla bla bla... now cloning the repo ....]


   2023-11-30T10:09:52.7097163Z remote: Counting objects:  59% (1919/3252)        
   2023-11-30T10:09:52.7097654Z remote: Counting objects:  60% (1952/3252)        
   2023-11-30T10:09:52.7098183Z remote: Counting objects:  61% (1984/3252)        
   2023-11-30T10:09:52.7098620Z remote: Counting objects:  62% (2017/3252)    

   [...]    


   2023-11-30T10:09:53.4081333Z Resolving deltas:  99% (409/413)
   2023-11-30T10:09:53.4083662Z Resolving deltas: 100% (413/413)
   2023-11-30T10:09:53.4084268Z Resolving deltas: 100% (413/413), done.
   2023-11-30T10:09:53.4828965Z From https://github.com/evilpoke/ppsat
   2023-11-30T10:09:53.4830562Z  * [new ref]         910aea5fd3c1d3f581680ecd49e207a264309ec1 -> origin/main

   [...now installing dependencies...]
   ....

   [...tests passing..]
   ```

   (full version of the logs [here](https://github.com/evilpoke/ppsat/actions/runs/7044950345/job/19173696187))

So far:

- I tried both Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 images.
- I noticed that GitHub used a special Docker container for their testing. My best guess on what that container is (based on the logs above) is [this one](https://hub.docker.com/layers/myoung34/github-runner/2.311.0-ubuntu-jammy/images/sha256-e7e1ca03fc3e03d3288ea3b01063721dc9222a8e4281e7c9e35d150acbe3226e?context=explore). So I tried this container instead of ubuntu:20.04 when building the container: same result
- The README instructions of the repository deviate from the ones of the pipeline. I also already tried the pipeline 'version' and also all sorts of 'combinations' between.

Comment: Hi, this is a question&answer forum. There are no questions in your post. So install gmp in your container and build, I do  not understand. Are you asking how to install ppsat, how to install ppsat in docker, why doesn't it work in your docker, why does it work in github actions. If your goal is "get this repository compiled on my machine" then asking about containers is a XY question? What happens when you "get this repository" and compile it on your machine, ignoring any github actions and docker containers (isn't it what you want?)

Comment: GitHub Actions' `ubuntu-latest` runners aren't just vanilla Ubuntu containers, they have [a bunch of stuff](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) installed to enable common dev workflows. If you want to test the workflow locally, you could use [`act`](https://github.com/nektos/act).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I already searched for prebuild docker images github is using but i can't find one. Based on your answer i will go ahead and try with 'act'

Answer (score 0):

I had to checkout `3d4d44bb561d422200ed90841065e90f3ed33875` from https://github.com/evilpoke/ppsat to get a version of the code consistent with the question.

I have wrapped up the entire build/test process in the Docker image. You can, of course, choose to do one or more of the last few stages in the `Dockerfile` manually within a running container.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  software-properties-common \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git \
  libssl-dev \
  wget \
  python3 \
  libgmp-dev \
  libgtest-dev \
  sudo

RUN cd /usr/src/gtest && \
    cmake CMakeLists.txt && \
    make && \
    cp ./lib/*.a /usr/lib

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emp-toolkit/emp-readme/master/scripts/install.py && \
    python3 install.py -install --tool --ot --sh2pc --ag2pc && \
    ldconfig && \
    rm -rf *

RUN git clone https://github.com/evilpoke/ppsat.git

WORKDIR /root/ppsat

RUN git checkout 3d4d44bb561d422200ed90841065e90f3ed33875
RUN cmake .
RUN make

RUN cd test && ./runTests.sh
```

Screenshot showing that build was successful.

[image]

Screenshot showing that tests run successfully.

[image]